# Overleaf is not reading my deluxetable.sty file

Tags: tables, overleaf, deluxetable

I have added a file called deluxetable.sty to a paper I am contributing to in Overleaf, however when I compile it, it is as if deluxetable were not there and I get the following error:

> LaTeX Error: Environment deluxetable* undefined.
>
> You have created an environment (using \begin{…} and \end{…} commands) which is not recognized. >Make sure you have included the required package for that environment in your preamble, and >that the environment is spelled correctly.

I have included the package in the preamble and have made sure that I haven't made any syntax errors.

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Basic setup. Most papers should leave these options alone.
\documentclass[fleqn,usenatbib]{mnras}

% MNRAS is set in Times font. If you don't have this installed (most LaTeX
% installations will be fine) or prefer the old Computer Modern fonts, comment
% out the following line
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
% Depending on your LaTeX fonts installation, you might get better results with one of these:
%\usepackage{mathptmx}
%\usepackage{txfonts}

\usepackage{deluxetable}
```

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have `\ProvidesPackage(deluxetable}` as the first line of `deluxetable.sty`?

Comment: If the package's `.sty` file is in your current project folder then your document should compile. Otherwise, I'm not sure what the problem could be.

Comment: _[Disclaimer/Disclosure: I'm a support personnel at Overleaf.]_ `deluxtable.sty` needs to be in your Overleaf project's top level, i.e. not within any folder, so you may need to drag the file out.

Comment: The file was already in the top level of my project. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @imnothere reviving this thread as there is no accepted answer here. The OP is asking about deluxetable* environment not deluxetable.